# HTml2Canvas renderiza sin imágenes de fondo, solo guarda texto

Tags: javascript, css, html2canvas

Estoy trabajando con la librería [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) para capturar el contenido de un `<div>` y guardarlo como imagen.

El problema se da al intentar capturar las imágenes de fondo del contenedor, pues únicamente me está trayendo texto.

```js
function fAgrega() {
  const options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    timeZone: 'UTC'
  };
  document.getElementById("Text2").value = document.getElementById("Text1").value;
  document.getElementById("Text4").value = document.getElementById("Text3").value;
  document.getElementById("Text6").value = new Date(document.getElementById("Text5").value).toLocaleDateString("es-CO", options);
}


$("#changewp").change(function() {
  var imageFileName = $(this).val();
  $(".fondo").css("background-image", "url('https://lauraz956.github.io/demos/assets/img/" + imageFileName + ".jpg')");
});


$(function() {
  $("#crearimagen").click(function() {
    html2canvas($("#contenido"), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        theCanvas = canvas;
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        /*
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
          saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png");
        });
        */
      }
    });
  });
});


$(function() {
  $("#uploadFile").on("change", function() {
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

    if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) { // only image file
      var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
      reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

      reader.onloadend = function() { // set image data as background of div
        $("#imagePreview").css("background-image", "url(" + this.result + ")");
        $(".texto_preview").remove();
      }
    }
  });
  $('#imagePreview').click(function() {
    $('#uploadFile').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://lauraz956.github.io/demos/assets/css/estilos.css">
<script src="https://lauraz956.github.io/demos/assets/js/filesaver.js"></script>
<script src="https://lauraz956.github.io/demos/assets/js/html2canvas.js"></script>


<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6">

        <h1>Datos</h1>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          Producto: <input id="Text1" type="text" onkeyup="fAgrega();" />

          <br><br> Seleccione:
          <select onchange="fAgrega()" id="Text3">
            <option>Opcion 1</option>
            <option>Opcion 2</option>
            <option>Opcion 3</option>
          </select>

          <br><br> Fecha: <input id="Text5" onchange="fAgrega()" type="date" name="fecha">

          <br><br>

          <label for="pictype">Fondo</label>
          <select id="changewp" name="changewp">
            <option value="p1">pic1</option>
            <option value="p2">pic2</option>
          </select>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row" id="contenido">

          <div class="col-md-12 fondo" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid;">

            <p>
              Su producto es <b><input id="Text2" type="text" class="preview_txt" /></b> y la seleccion es la <input id="Text4" type="text" class="preview_txt" /> del día <input id="Text6" type="text" class="preview_txt" />
            </p>
            <div id="imagePreview"></div>
            <span class="texto_preview">Subir Imagen</span>
            <input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="image" class="img" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <br><br>
        <button id="crearimagen" class="form-control">Crear Imagen</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

La captura se realiza una vez seleccionados los datos a introducir manualmente desde unos `input`, la imagen de fondo están guardadas en el servidor y la imagen que sube el usuario para previsualizarse lo hace desde su equipo localmente.

Estos datos a capturar son los que se encuentren dentro de

```
<div class="row" id="contenido">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dos cosas a tener en cuenta:

La función `allowTaint` debe ser `true`, según la documentación para añadir imágenes incrustadas, esta propiedad debe ser `true`.

```
$(function() {
      $("#crearimagen").click(function() {
        html2canvas($("#contenido"), {
          allowTaint: true,
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            /*
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
              saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png");
            });
            */
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

Por otro lado, en el CSS, tanto del `background` como de la imagen que insertas dinámicamente, la propiedad `background-size` debe tener los valores `100% 100%` en lugar de un `background-size: cover`. Me late que la librería pasa por alto el `cover`.

Este es el CSS al que me refiero:

```
.fondo {
background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#imagePreview {
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Perfecto! Mil gracias por el apoyo!.

Comment: Vale, con cariño :D Que sigas desarrollando con todo el power 2.0!!! :D

Comment: Una consulta, yo hago una capture de una gráfica de google charts y la guardo sin problemas desde la pc pero cuando la hago desde mi móvil solo se guarda el fondo y no la gráfica....

Comment: eso podría ser tranquilamente otra pregunta debido a que el entorno es diferente, ¿te animas a lanzar la pregunta indicando el sistema operativo de tu móvil, además del navegador y de la versión que uses?

Comment: hola espero puedas ayudarme con mi [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488963/convertir-html-a-imagen-con-html2canvas-y-canvas2image), es similar a esta, el error que me arroja es: **DOMException: Error al ejecutar 'toDataURL' en 'HTMLCanvasElement': los lienzos contaminados no se pueden exportar.**