# Convertir HTML a imagen con html2canvas y canvas2image

Tags: html5, html2canvas

tengo un un div html con mas elementos dentro el cual quiero convertir a imagen para ser descargada, esta parte ya funciona respetando el CSS, el problema esta en que necesito que ese div tenga una imagen como background, posteriormente le agregue el background-image al div y la imagen ya no se genera, el error que me arroja es:

> DOMException: Error al ejecutar 'toDataURL' en 'HTMLCanvasElement': los lienzos contaminados no se pueden exportar.

el codigo html es:

```
<div class="col-8 contenedorC" id="contenedorC">
    <div id="ifrm" name="ifrm" class="ifrm">
        <div class="cajas c1">
            <div id="lienzo" class="frente lienzo" style="width: 73%; height: 51%;">
                <div class="lienzoBack1" id="lienzoBack1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0.83; background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></div> <!-- div con imagen de fondo-->
                <!-- Mas etiquetas p ul li etc que no me generan errores en convercion a imagen -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    <!-- inserto imagen de fondo -->
    var backgroundI1 = document.getElementById("lienzoBack1");
    backgroundI1.style.backgroundImage = 'url(./imagenFondo.jpg)';
</script>
<button class="btnImg" id="btnImg" onclick="f()">img</button> <!-- Boton para descargar como imagen -->
```

en el script tengo:

```
function f(){
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#contenedorC")).then(canvas => {
        let d = canvas.toDataURL();
        console.log(d);
        return Canvas2Image.saveAsImage(canvas, null, null, "png", "img");
    });
}
```

No conozco la forma en como se convierte la imagen de fondo a canvas, ya cheque la documentacion pero no logro con el resultado, me podrían ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pensé en eliminar la pregunta, pero decidí dejarla por si a alguien le puede servir en un futuro. El ejemplo anterior es correcto y funciona! después de investigar por un buen rato llegue a la conclusión de que el motivo esta en que:

Por motivos de seguridad, la unidad local del cliente se declara con otro dominio y mancha el lienzo. Esto se debe a que al estar realizando pruebas en mi PC estaba ejecutando el proyecto sin ningún servidor en mi caso (PHP) y la imagen la reconocía por así decirlo como confidencial las soluciones posibles están entre:

- Publicar la imagen en un sitio que admita el uso compartido entre dominios (como dropbox.com o GitHub). Asegurarse de poner la imágenes en la carpeta pública de Dropbox y también establecer la bandera de origen cruzado al descargar la imagen ( ...)var img=new Image(); img.crossOrigin="anonymous"
- Instalar un servidor web en el equipo de desarrollo como IIS o Apache depende de su proyecto.

La solución mas factible y por obvias razones es la segunda.

Al final termine convirtiendo el div en imagen con canvas y posteriormente pasarlo a pdf, probé pasando el div directamente a PDF pero la resolución era muy deficiente el proyecto quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="col-8 contenedorC" id="contenedorC">
    <div id="ifrm" name="ifrm" class="ifrm">
        <div class="cajas c1">
            <div id="lienzo" class="frente lienzo" style="width: 73%; height: 51%;">
                <div class="lienzoBack1" id="lienzoBack1" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0.83; background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;"></div> <!-- div con imagen de fondo-->
                <!-- Mas etiquetas p ul li etc que no me generan errores en convercion a imagen -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btnImg" id="btnImg" onclick="f()">img</button>
<button class="btnPdf" id="btnPdf" >pdf</button>
```

El script:

```
//Convierte el div a imagen y la descarga
function f(){
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#contenedorC")).then(canvas => {
        return Canvas2Image.saveAsImage(canvas, null, null, "png", "img");
    });
}

$(function() {
    $("#btnPdf").click(function() {
        html2canvas($("#contenedorC"), {
            allowTaint: true,
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/PNG").replace("image/PNG","image/octet-stream");
                var pdf = new jsPDF('l','mm','letter');
            
                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
                pdf.save("download.pdf");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Las librerías que utilice fueron:

- [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)
- [canvas2image](https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image/blob/master/canvas2image.js)
- [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

Espero y les sirva

Comment: Recuerda marcar como aceptada a tu respuesta :)